# Change value of the variable to value of another

Tags: java

i am try change value the variable NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL  from value 9 to 19 by By a function " IF "

```
public class Constant {


public static int NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL = 9  ; 

public static int NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL (int[] args ) {

    if( NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL  == 10 ) {
        NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL = 11 ; //i want change value to 11
    }

    else if( NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL  == 9 ) {
        NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL = 19 ; //i want change value to 19
    }

    else {
        NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL = 10 ; //
    }

}
```

Which is the error in my code?

Comment: Why are you passing `int[]` as a parameter?

Comment: Tip: Learn to follow Java naming conventions. A method name should start with a lowercase letter, and should not be all uppercase. Only a constant (a variable that does not vary) should be named in all uppercase. Tip # 2: Study the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) by Oracle, free of charge.

Comment: i am begginer in java and android studio

Comment: Change your method signature to `public static void NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL (int[] args ) {`

Comment: **that code does not compile** ... or where do you return an integer value as stated in the method signature?

Comment: and what's the purpose of the param `args`? it looks like you just copied it from the Java `main` method and changed it to `int` type for whatever reason

Comment: I want to correct my code please

Comment: tell me, what is the purpose of this method? why the array as arguments? why the return value? honestly, do you know what you did here? or is it just copy and paste from something that you have seen somewhere else?

Comment: yes i copy this code but i want this code for reskin android my brother

Comment: well, I understand. but you'll need to understand the basics first I guess which is currently not the case. good luck

Answer (score 1):

The "if" logic works.  The return value `int` is missing.  This is a simple problem, you should learn to test it yourself.

```
public class ifTTest {

   public static int NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL = 9;

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      int[] testVectors = { 1, 10, 9, };
      int[] testOutput =  {10, 11, 19 };
      for( int test=0; test < testVectors.length; test++ ) {
         NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL = testVectors[test];
         NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL( null );
         if( NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL != testOutput[test] )
            System.out.println( "error" );
      }
   }

   public static int NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL( int[] args ) {
      if( NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL == 10 ) {
         NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL = 11; //i want change value to 11
      } else if( NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL == 9 ) {
         NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL = 19; //i want change value to 19
      } else {
         NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL = 10; //
      }
      return 0;
   }

}
```